# EMV - Unable to Generate AC command from CDOL1

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I have successfully retrieved CDOL1 which is

```
9F02 06 - Authorised amount of the transaction (excluding adjustments)
9F03 06 - Secondary amount associated with the transaction representing a cashback amount
9F1A 02 - the country of the terminal
95   05 - Status of the different functions as seen from the terminal
5F2A 02 - the currency code of the transaction
9A   03 - Local date that the transaction was authorised
9C   01 - the type of financial transaction 
9F37 04 - Value to provide variability and uniqueness to the generation of a cryptogram
```

How do I create the Generate AC command based on this CDOL1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on CDOL1 you would next assemble the CDOL1 related data (i.e. a list of the data object values referenced by the tags in CDOL1):

```
[9F02 06   (Amount, authorized, numeric)]:   000000001000 (that's 1.00)
[9F03 06   (Amount, other, numeric)]:        000000000000 (that's 0.00)
[9F1A 02   (Terminal country code)]:         0040 (Austria)
[95 05     (Terminal verification results)]: 0000000000 (or whatever TVR you need)
[5F2A 02   (Transaction currency code)]:     0978 (Euro)
[9A 03     (Transaction date)]:              150528 (2015-05-28)
[9C 01     (Transaction type)]:              00 (whatever transaction type need)
[9F37 04   (Unpredictable number)]:          12345678
```

You would then wrap that data into the DATA field of the GENERATE AC command APDU:

```
80 AE 5000 1D 000000001000 000000000000 0040 0000000000 0978 150528 00 12345678 00
```

In response to this, you would either get a response message data field wrapped in tag 77 (format 2) that consists of several data objects. E.g. if no CDA is performed, this could look like:

```
77 xx
  [Cryptogram Information Data]     9F27 01 80
  [Application Transaction Counter] 9F36 02 001B
  [Application Cryptogram]          9F26 08 B31B2D16 69860BD5
  [Issuer Application Data]         9F10 yy ...
9000 [SW: success]
```

Alternatively you could also get response message data field wrapped in tag 80 (format 1). In that case, the value is a concatenated list of implicit data objects (tag + length fields are not present):

```
80 xx
  [9F27 01 (Cryptogram Information Data)]:     80
  [9F36 02 (Application Transaction Counter)]: 001B
  [9F26 08 (Application Cryptogram)]:          9F26 08 B31B2D16 69860BD5
  [9F10 yy (Issuer Application Data)]:         ...
9000 [SW: success]
```

Comment: Ok , can you please again retrieve the data from this response 
80128000 1bb31b2d 1669860b d506010a 03a0f000 9000
It would be really helpful

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, GENERATE AC command is working on MC AND VC but it gives 6A81 on AMEX card. CDOL is same as above, any reason ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the AMEX specific protocol variants of EMV, so no, I can't tell you what might be wrong/different there.

Comment: try to add tag - 9F35 01 9F34 03 in your CDOL 1 list. and share your output please